# On the online version of my blog posts disappear

Tags: posts, categories, htaccess, accessibility

I lose posts after a few weeks. So as of today there is a gap form April 14 to March 17. Do you know what happens. how can i rectify it? And then there is a gap

Comment: Are the records still present in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Just based on your post alone, it is hard to identify the problem, as it could be anything.
First and foremost, I recommend you take a backup of your current site (including the database). If you don't know how to, ask someone else trustworthy, or the company that hosts your site.

Now, as for why this happen, there are many possible reasons, such as :

1. Malware
2. Corrupted database
3. Plugin issues

Until there is more information provided, it is hard for me to say what the issue at hand is, and how to go about rectifying it.